# How do I get jackson to find my key deserializer?

Tags: java, jackson

Here's my class (getters and setters omitted):

```
public class ClassWithAMap {

    @JsonProperty("map")
    @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = RangeDeserializer.class)
    private Map<Range<Instant>, String> map;

    @JsonCreator
    public ClassWithAMap(Map<Range<Instant>, String> map) {
      this.map = map;
    }

  }
```

The RangeSerializer looks like this:

```
public class RangeDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {

    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModules(
                new JavaTimeModule(),
                new Jdk8Module(),
                new GuavaModule(),
                new ParameterNamesModule());
    }

    @Override
    public Range<Instant> deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        TypeReference<Range<Instant>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Range<Instant>>() {
        };
        Range<Instant> range = objectMapper().readValue(key, typeRef);
        return range;
    }
}
```

And the main code that uses these is this:

```
        Map<Range<Instant>,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        Range<Instant> key = Range.greaterThan(Instant.now());
        map.put(key, "some value");
        ClassWithAMap classWithAMap = new ClassWithAMap(map);

        String jsonInput = objectMapper()
                .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(classWithAMap);

        ClassWithAMap classWithMap = objectMapper()
                .readValue(jsonInput,
                ClassWithAMap.class);
```

The last statement gives me this error:

```
InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class com.google.common.collect.Range<java.time.Instant>]
```

and, sure enough, it never calls my deserializer. I've missed some step registering the deserializer, though I've compared it to a similar setup with a custom class instead of `Range<Instant>` which works fine, an I can't see the difference. Anyone know what I did wrong? I'm guessing something to do with the generic but I haven't got further.

I'm using jackson 2.9.9 and Java 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move all annotations to constructor:

```
class ClassWithAMap {

    private Map<Range<Instant>, String> map;

    @JsonCreator
    public ClassWithAMap(
            @JsonProperty("map")
            @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = RangeDeserializer.class)
            Map<Range<Instant>, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```