# Jackson - include JsonTypeInfo for Map keys

Tags: java, json, jackson

In Java, I need to serialize an object that is wrapper for `Map<Object, Object>`. I would like to have a class type info included in generated Json and I'm able to do it via `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)`. However the type info is included only for map values but not keys.

For example:

```
@Data
public class FunnyObject {

    @JsonProperty(value = "fields")
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
    private Map<Object, Object> fields = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Initializing:

```
Map<Object, Object> fields = new HashMap<>();
fields.put("Date", new Date());
fields.put(new Date(), "ups");
fields.put(MyTypes.TYPE_B, "Reversed");

FunnyObject funnyObject = new FunnyObject();
funnyObject.setFields(fields);
```

MyTypes Enum:

```
public enum MyTypes {
    TYPE_A("hello"),
    TYPE_B("World");

    private String txt;

    MyTypes(String txt) {
        this.txt = txt;
    }
}
```

The generated Json is this, where class type info is included only for the value.
Howe I can include this also for the Key?

```json
{
    "fields": {
        "2021-01-25T13:28:18.718+00:00": "ups",
        "TYPE_B": "Reversed",
        "Date": [
            "java.util.Date",
            1611581298718
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `JSON` key is always a `string`. How would you like to provide key type together with key name? You could write your own serialiser and annotate `fields` property with [@JsonSerialize](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html#keyUsing--). [Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map), [Jackson custom KeyDeserializer for Map, excluding entries where key is null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59571479/51591), [How do I get jackson to find my key deserializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59423616/51591)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Michał Ziober answered this question in a comment to my original post

"JSON key is always a string"